# behat can not interact with invisible field

Tags: behat

Does anyone have suggestions on what's wrong with my code?  Here's the code:

```
     echo $this->find("css","#address-container")->getHtml();
     $field = $this->find("css","#address-container .region input");
     echo $field->isVisible() ? "I can see myself!!!" : "no can not see";
     echo $field->getAttribute('type');
     $field->setValue("ON");
```

When I run the test, this is the result

```
  │         <legend>Address</legend>
  │         <div class="field city">
  │           <label>*City</label>
  │           <input class="required city" name="address_add[0][city]" value="" type="text">
  │         </div>
  │         <div class="field region">
  │           <label>*Prov./State</label>
  │           <input class="required region" name="address_add[0][region]" value="" type="text">
  │         </div>
  │         <div class="field country">
  │           <label>*Country</label>
  │           <input class="required country" name="address_add[0][country]" value="" type="text">
  │         </div>
  │     no can not seetext
  Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
  Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
  System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.15-x86_64-linode81',                                            java.version: '1.8.0_121'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown (WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotVisible)
```

I am expecting the `#address-container .region input` to be VISIBLE.  When I go to my browser and go through the steps manually, I do see the region field being visible.  Other things I checked for are:

- there are no other region input fields on the page
- if I replace region with city or country, everything works fine
- there is no delayed javascript call manipulating the region input field

What else could be causing the region field to be hidden?  Are there better tools for me to use to troubleshoot this issue?

**UPDATE**

If I swapped the position of the region and country html like this:

```
  │         <div class="field country">
  │           <label>*Country</label>
  │           <input class="required country" name="address_add[0][country]" value="" type="text">
  │         </div>
  │         <div class="field region">
  │           <label>*Prov./State</label>
  │           <input class="required region" name="address_add[0][region]" value="" type="text">
  │         </div>
```

Then region becomes visible.  But if Change my behat code to look for country, now it's country that's invisible!

So is behat seeing something different that I odn't see in a REAL browser?

Comment: Try to search this selector via inspect in the browser to see if returns a single element. You might need to add a wait, at first you can use a blind wait like `sleep(2);` to test and after you can add a conditional wait. Please provide the html snippet of the entire #address-container form.

Comment: Thanks lauda.  I just updated my question.  If I reverse the order of the html nodes for region and country, then region is visible and country is not.  Even though when i look at things through human eyes in my web browser, i can see them both being visible...weird

Comment: Try a selector like: `#address-container input.region`  or `#address-container input[name*=region]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that selenium had a monitor resolution of 800x600.  So the elements were actually out of the view port at times.  When I increase the monitor resolution to 1366x768, everything worked fine.  I was able to debug this by using selenium screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question is really about Selenium (because you are using it as a driver: `Driver info: driver.version: unknown (WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotVisible)`).

With Selenium, if its behaviour is different from what you are seeing in a browser... Try to add a small delay. I can be `sleep(1)` or something more clever.

Really many issues came from the fact that you try to access the page directly after the load (when some JS still hasn't finished yet).